# Confusion over "order is important".

Tags: combinatorics

> There are 6 elevators in the skyscraper. How many ways can 10 people on the ground floor get on, if the elevators are distinguishable, people are distinguishable, elevator may be empty, the order of getting on is important.

I'm confused which interpretation of "order of getting on is important" is correct:

1. Let's separate people into queues for elevators. This can be done by making one big queue and then separating it (stars and bars). $$10!\binom{10+6-1}{6-1}$$
2. Let's put people into one big "global" queue. Then every person in the queue decides which elevator will they choose. $$10!6^{10}$$

Are those interpretations both valid? Which is adequate for this question? Thanks!

Comment: For the respective interpretations, both answers look correct to me. And which of these two interpretations is described in this question is not clear to me either. Like you, I'm not sure if they mean that the order of all people is important or only within each elevator. To me this looks like a somewhat poorly worded question. I'd ask for clarification from whomever gave you the question, or if it's homework from those who are going to grade it.

Comment: @zipirovich I (moderately) disagree.  I think the phrase *getting on* typically connotes getting on a specific elevator, as opposed to choosing which elevator to get on.  See my answer.

Comment: I'm doing past test problems from my university and I have no idea who the setter was so I couldn't really ask them. Thanks for clarification, I'd definitely ask for more information if it was in an exam setting though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first interpretation is correct for the problem.  Here, I am assuming that the order that each person gets on a specific elevator is important.

The second interpretation **would** be correct, if (instead), the order that each person decides which elevator to get on is (**also**) deemed important.

For example, if person-1 gets on elevator-1, and person-2 gets on elevator-2, the first interpretation does not regard person-1 **deciding** before person-2 as relevant.  The 2nd interpretation does, so the 2nd interpretation would regard as distinct, person-2 choosing elevator-2 and then person-1 choosing elevator-1.